# Windows 10 boot disk decryption

Tags: windows-10, boot, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I have a windows machine that no longer boots. I receive a `All boot options are tried. Press <F4> key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration` error when I try booting. I was planning on just copying the important data off through ubuntu and reinstalling windows, however I came to find out that starting in windows 10 the boot drive is encrypted by default causing all of my data to be inaccessible. I have tried the usual repair steps (repair using a windows bootable usb, running the `/fixmbr` etc commands), however none of them fixed the booting issue. I have a couple of questions related to this.

1. Does anyone know of any other techniques that I can try?
2. Does anyone know the correct term that I should be searching to find more information on this issue (I am not even sure what encryption technique is used for this. BitLocker? Something else?)

I have tried to find decryption keys on my Microsoft Account, but as I did not manually specify that I wanted to encrypt a drive I believe they were not backed up.

My priority is recovering files first, and then reinstalling windows next.

Comment: Have you been asked during the boot for a BitLocker key?

Comment: I have not. The OS does not even boot. I believe there is something that was corrupted in the boot sequence. So, without a separate boot disk I can't get past the bios

Comment: Can you manage boot successfully into the BIOS? Or boot Windows from USB media?

Comment: I can access the bios and I can boot from a USB as well

Comment: If you boot from USB into the Command Prompt, can you see the disk and your files?

Comment: I just tried it again, and I must have done something differently than last time. I am able to see the disk and files if I go through the command prompt

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issue seems to have solved itself, without further details given.

Comment: @ninjzeus - You should submit an answer instead of editing your question to include your solution.  This way, you can be rewarded for asking and answering a question, which future users might benefit from.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will answer my own question then!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see the disk and the files when booting from USB, the disk
is not encrypted with Bitlocker and probably can be repaired.

You may use the USB boot media to repair the boot code on the disk.

For detailed instructions with screenshots see the article
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: When I run startup repair, I get a `Startup repair couldn't repair your PC` and when I try to read the log file, it doesn't exist. I don't have an `srt` folder in the `System32/LogFiles` folder

Comment: In that case, use the boot into the Command Prompt to save your data and do [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and should keep your data and settings, but better to take precautions.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**
I would like to share what I did to solve (hopefully both of my problems). Thanks to `harrymc` for giving me further ideas to test.

**Recovering data**

- When booting with a usb disk, I was able to access the command prompt. From here, UI was able to swap to the internal drive and the data was not encrypted (use `C:` to swap not `cd C:`)
- Once on the C drive, I inserted an external drive (G in my case) that was big enough to hold of of the data. From there, I used the command `robocopy /E /xj /r:2 /w:5 /copy:DATSO . G:\backup\` to copy all of the data from the internal drive to my external drive's backup folder.
- once this finished (took approximately 1 day for me), I inserted the drive into another computer, but the backup folder was missing in the file explorer.
- Investigating through cmd, the folder did exist it was just hidden, and even with hidden files/folders option checked, the folder did not appear.
- To fix this, I ran the command `attrib -h -s d:\backup` where the D drive is the same external drive that I copied data to. After this command was run, all folders and files were visible on my second machine.

**Fixing the booting**

- Still working on it. I have been quite busy. I will update when/if I find a solution.
  Current status:
- After none of the repair options working (from cmd, the bootable disk or otherwise, excluding 3rd party programs), I decided to to a full reinstall.
- Attempting the reinstall is causing problems. I get a `0X80300024` error code when trying to reinstall. I initially thought that this may be because the installer is unable to overwrite the previous windows (for some reason), so through linux I deleted all the partitions (MADE SURE MY DATA WAS BACKED UP BEFORE), and tried again. Still no luck. The error code seems to suggest that it is an issue with my ssd. I am running a nvme samsung evo 970 plus, which last time I checked was not affected by the recent issue with samsung drives (but [this post](https://nascompares.com/2023/02/02/samsung-980-pro-970-evo-plus-pm9a1-and-more-reporting-failures-everything-we-know-so-far/) seems to suggest otherwise). I think I will visit a samsung service center to see if I can get it figured out.

Final update:
I visited the service center twice. At the first level triage they were able to verify that the disk failed. At the second level, they re-verified that the disk failed and they gave me a new drive. Both times it took about 15 minutes. They were unable to tell me what the exact cause of the failure was, but based on what happened, it seems likely that it was the firmware issue in my case.

In conclusion, if you can, backup the data as I did, and then start fresh on a new drive.